# Tests skipped after Rails upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, shoulda

After upgrading from Rails 4.0.3 to Rails 4.1.0.rc1 test classes which inherit from ActiveSupport::TestCase
stopped being executed.

We use shoulda contexts in all our tests. MiniTest was upgraded from 4.7.5 to 5.3.0. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like shoulda contexts are sipmply skipped.

Comment: I think I found the answer:

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-context/pull/39

It is not in master branch yet.